# Sample file for augeas

Tags: file, ubuntu, command-line, sample, augeas

I am searching for example of file which could be passed to the augeas:

```
augeas --f example/file
```

So far my file looks like this:

```
 set /files/etc/hosts/01/ipaddr 127.0.2.1
 set /files/etc/hosts/01/alias[1] testy
 set /files/etc/hosts/01/alias[2] test
 save
```

And if I pass the file to the augeas it tells me this:

```
 error: Failed to execute command
 saving failed (run 'print /augeas//error' for details)
```

Obviously, I did what the command line told me:

```
 janipav@janipav:~$ print /augeas//error
 Warning: unknown mime-type for "/augeas//error" -- using "application/octet-stream"
 Error: no such file "/augeas//error"
```

So, I am pretty much stuck here. Googling did not provide me anything, so I hope to find answer here. Thanks

Comment: Note that the command `print /augeas//error` is something that should be done inside of augeas, not at the shell. If you had done that instead of your `save` command, or right before the `save` command, then augeas would show you what the error messages were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canonical` node is mandatory for `hosts` entries with the `Hosts.lns` lens, so you need:

```
set /files/etc/hosts/01/ipaddr 127.0.2.1
set /files/etc/hosts/01/canonical localhost2
set /files/etc/hosts/01/alias[1] testy
set /files/etc/hosts/01/alias[2] test
save
```

Note that this change is not idempotent, it will create a new entry at every run.