# How to make Augeas script with conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, augeas

Ok, I learned [how to make a script in augeas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517974/sample-file-for-augeas) but as stated in the answer, the simple file creates a new entry in the file.

I need some conditions (if - else) or at least if (condition) not true do...

I was searching on the internet and found only examples in Puppet. But I dont want to install puppet. Is there a way to tell Augeas only to add node if conditions are (not) met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no logic operators in the Augeas language (yet). See [this thread](https://www.redhat.com/archives/augeas-devel/2014-January/msg00003.html) for more info on the status of adding it (possibly embedding lua in the C bindings).

If you need such logic, I'd recommend you currently use bindings (Ruby, Python, PHP, Perl, etc. You choose ;))

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping for, but thank you anyway :)